# 64bit name mangling for c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, name-mangling

I have a bit of code which has the following line

```
  #pragma comment(linker, "/include:_test@12")
```

The project which uses this code works fine when I compile the code using C++ Visual Studio 2010 with configuration type 32bit (I am also on a 32 bit windows machine).

I get a link error when I change the machine to 64bit and use x64 configuration which compiling with C++ Visual Studio 2010.

Is C++ name mangling different for 32bit vs 64bit? If so, where can I find the 64bit C++ name mangling conventions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes the name mangling is different between 32 and 64 bit. A reasonable article covering the exact formats can be [found here](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling). You can tell the major differences pretty quickly, however, by simply compiling to both targets and examining the resulting map files. From my experience they're *almost* identical (64bit adds a small datum, potentially changes others).

Simple sample: `void foo();`

```
32bit: ?foo@A@@QAEXXZ
64bit: ?foo@A@@QEAAXXZ
```

For non-mangled std call, the length suffix can be substantially different, depending on the parameter stack usage. The default 64-bit settings for VC++ do not prepend underscores nor does it encode length-suffixes. The following was compiled both 32/64bit configs with pure out-of-the-box settings:

```
extern "C" int _stdcall func2(int, int, char*);

32bit: _func2@12
64bit: func2
```

Not much point there, is there.

Completing the circuit, unmangled _cdecl, which does this:

```
extern "C" int _cdecl func2(int, int, char*);

32bit: _func2
64bit: func2
```

If it seems like they went out of their way to make you know what you're pulling-in or exporting-out, evidence suggests you're probably correct.

Comment: It may be quite different actually... If `test` receives three pointer parameters then it will change from `12` to `24`... Ah, also this is not a C++ function. It seems to be an `stdcall` C function.

Comment: where can i learn about this. i am new to these concepts. also i think mine is a stdcall and the example you gave is for cdecl. i have couple of other calls like #pragma comment(linker, "/export:test@0=test") how should i change those. a reference clarifying these will be great.

Comment: There are a host of documents on C++ name mangling (I linked you one of them). You appear to be using extern "C" _stdcall for your exports, which, as demonstrated above, are different in 32.vs.64-bit. There are articles literally all over MS and Wiki. Though VB-related, I like [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt232c9t(v=vs.71).aspx) as it does a decent job of talking about it. One way or another, though, you're going to have to clean up your #pragmas to #ifdef WIN64 and either import or export the appropriate names, I'm afraid.

Comment: From what I can tell, the only calling conventions available for 64-bit systems are `vectorcall` and the default x64 calling convention( which seems to be a version of `fastcall`, from what I can find online).  So, `__cdecl`, `__stdcall`, `__fastcall`, and `__thiscall` are all ignored when compiling as 64-bit.

Comment: The Wikipedia page has been migrated to: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling